# How to forward nginx proxy protocol in chained proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to chain an nginx `proxy_pass` from another nginx `proxy_pass`.

In the second nginx instance, there is a header like this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

However, this takes the scheme from the first nginx instance, which is `http`.

This works for internal LAN requests. But the client is visiting `https`. So this needs to be:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

This way it works for the client, but now internal requests no longer work due to failed CSRF verification.

I want to use the same scheme as the initial request, which is forwarded by the first nginx instance as:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

How can I reference this value in the second nginx instance?

Comment: If you do not set the header value, the original value should be passed through transparently.

Comment: This works! Thank you. I did not know they were passed through, it didn't occur to me to try this out.